# Firebird equivalent to H2 mixed mode and serialized mode?

Tags: client-server, database-connection, firebird, h2

Does anyone know how to set Firebird into mixed mode like H2 can with the AUTO_SERVER=TRUE option?

The H2 automatic mixed mode is described [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode).

What about serialized mode?

Notice it should be possible because it is mentioned [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq46/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Firebird server - by default - accepts multiple connections. You don't have to do configure anything to enable that. The only exception is if the administrator of the server restricted access for maintenance.

Firebird embedded itself cannot serve as a normal server (accepting connections from outside the client application that embeds it), but depending on the Firebird version and the OS it is possible that the database file can be shared with a 'normal' Firebird server on the same machine.

Your second link is about accessing a database on network drive, which is not possible (or at least prevented by default) because that can cause corruption by limitations of locking and forced write guarantees. Also understand that in a database server like Firebird all clients of a single database (should) access the same server, and the server accesses a database file local to the server machine.

Comment: Your first sentence has nothing to do with mixed mode, your second sentence If I get it correctly implies mixed mode is not possible (please explain "it is possible that the database file can be shared with a 'normal' Firebird server on the same machine"). Your third sentence implies serialized mode is not possible (Access permits it).

Comment: @dendini You are trying to shoehorn definitions of a specific database on another database. If you think my answer is insufficient, then please expand your question and clearly describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @dendini Also understand that Firebird is a database **server** a concept like mixed mode or what you call serialized mode doesn't make a lot of sense for a database server, because you have a single server that is used by **all** clients

Comment: I used H2 nomenclature to make clear what I meant and provided reference links to avoid any misunderstanding, I don't want to shoehorn H2 on Firebird, just want to know what of those 2 features are available on Firebird regardless of their specific naming. Mixed mode makes a lot of sense in an embedded database like H2 so Firebird might have given it as well, serialized mode is available in Access and is an experimental feature in H2.

Comment: @dendini Firebird doesn't provide this. The idea is embedded can be used from one application, one user, if you need access for more applications or more users, then you replace it with a normal Firebird server install.